# Cannot return the false statement

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The problem is that I cannot return a false value in the binary tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int Identification;
    string full_name;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

Node *newNode(int id, string name)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->Identification = id;
    temp->full_name = name;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

Node* insert(Node* node, int id, string name)
{
    if ( node == NULL)
    {
        return newNode(id,name);
    }
    
    if(id < node->Identification)
    {
        node->left = insert(node->left, id, name);
    }
    else if (id > node->Identification)
    {
        node->right = insert(node->right, id, name);
    }
    
    return node;
}

bool search(Node* root, int id)
{
    if (root == NULL || root->Identification == id)
    {
        cout << root->full_name << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if (root != NULL && root->Identification != id)
    {
        cout << "Record not found";
        return false;
    }
    
    
    if (root->Identification < id)
    {
        return search(root->right, id);
    }
    return search(root->left, id);
    
}


int main()
{
    int searching;
    Node *root = NULL;

    root = insert(root, 1021, "John Williams");
    root = insert(root, 1057, "Bill Witherspoon");
    root = insert(root, 2487, "Jennifer Twain");
    root = insert(root, 3769, "Sophia Lancaster");
    root = insert(root, 1017, "Debbie Reece");
    root = insert(root, 1275, "George McMullen");
    root = insert(root, 1899, "Ashley Smith");
    root = insert(root, 4218, "Josh Plemmons");
  
  cout << "Enter ID to find employe name ";
  cin >> searching;
  search(root, searching);

    return 0;
}
```

It works when I types like `444` and returns `false`, `No Id found`. And when I type `1021`, it return `true`, `John Williams`. But when I use other IDs like for example `1899`, which correspond with `Ashley smith`, it returns `false`. So I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: DANGER: In `if (root == NULL || root->Identification == id)` if `root` is null, `cout << root->full_name << endl;` has an ill doom. You can't get the `full_name` of a null pointer.

Comment: We can't help you debug this unless you edit your question to include the source code for the `insert` function. Also, by the way, your `search` function contains undefined behavior: if `root == NULL` then it dereferences `root->full_name`.

Comment: `search` only ever looks at the root node. The recursive call to `search` is unreachable, the function always returns before that.

Comment: *"I cannot return the false statement in the binary tree."* -- Right, you would return a false **value**, not a statement. (The statement does the returning; it is not the thing returned.) I could fix that much for you, but I'm stuck on the second part. Returning in a data structure (e.g. a binary tree) does not make sense; one returns from a function. Which function is not returning what you intend?

Comment: *"It works when I types [...]"* -- A better [mre] would not require user input. Instead of asking for an ID and getting the ID from the user, hardcode the two searches. For example: `std::cout << "Search for 444: " << search(root, 444) << '\n';` `std::cout << "Search for 1021: " << search(root, 1021) << '\n';`

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

In the function `search`, the code

```
if (root == NULL || root->Identification == id)
{
    cout << root->full_name << endl;
    return true;
}
```

does not make sense, because if the content of the `if` block is executed due to `root == NULL`, then you will dereference this `NULL` pointer by using the expression `root->full_name`, which will invoke undefined behavior (i.e. likely cause a segmentation fault).

Also, in that function, the following code is unreachable:

```
if (root->Identification < id)
{
    return search(root->right, id);
}
return search(root->left, id);
```

It is unreachable because the conditions of both preceding `if` statements would have to evaluate `false` for this code to be reached, but that is not possible. It is not possible for the conditions

```
if (root == NULL || root->Identification == id)
```

and

```
if (root != NULL && root->Identification != id)
```

to both evaluate to `false`. The second one will always be `true` if the first one is `false`.

The `search` function should look like this:

```
bool search(Node* root, int id)
{
    if ( root == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ( id < root->Identification )
    {
        return search( root->left, id );
    }

    if ( id > root->Identification )
    {
        return search( root->right, id );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now that function will return `true` also when you enter `1899`.